# What is hvc0? (appearing in "who" list)

Tags: ubuntu, security, users, xen

I have an Ubuntu Server, and when I type `who`, to see who's connected, I can see that there's a user connected, and instead of being logged to a `pts/x`, he's connected to `hvc0`. Is there something to worry about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hvc0` is the Xen hypervisor console.  Is the administrator of the Xen host logging into your virtual machine?

Comment: Well the user who's connected on hvc0 is me... But I don't even know how I managed to connect there. lol